# Where can I find the phone number of the SIM card that I have in an iPad?

Tags: ipad, sim

Is there a way, directly on the iPad, to find out which phone number is associated to the MicroSIM which it is using?

I can't find it in the menus, currently.

Is there an easy way to find it directly, like on an iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [Settings → General → About → Celluar Data Number](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsVD0j9zC3Q)

Comment: Hm, this is probably the way to go, but it gives me "Unknown", for some reason.

Comment: @Gnoupi, I've had the same problem on my iPhone. I don't believe you can retrieve the phonenumber from your iPad then. To resolve it I had to put the SIM card in an old Sony-Ericsson phone and edit it myself.

Comment: @Gnoupi Then you should try to retrieve it via iTunes using this [Apple info](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4061).

Comment: @Gerry According to the video you can retrieve "phonenumbers" from your SIM using the iPad. But if this is a specific SIM for an iPad, the operator may have decided to not use a cellular data number because they don't need it for billing purposes.

Comment: @gentmatt - It's not showing up in iTunes either, so I guess it's coherent with the rest. Since this is based on a pre-paid card, it might be the reason why the provider doesn't show the number. Your solution is the one for most other cases, though.

Answer (score 1):

From the device, you can get this through Settings > Tap General > Tap About > Scroll to view the IMEI/ICCID/my Number.

Answer (score 1):

Settings → General → About → Celluar Data Number *should* theoretically work, but on many iPads it doesn't.  See also

[Cellular Data Number is "Unknown" on some iPads](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66454/cellular-data-number-is-unknown-on-some-ipads)

Our provider is AT&T, and on my account pages, e.g., https://www.att.com/my/#/wirelessUsage, I can see the "phone" number for the iPad.

Answer (score -1):

dial #100# and the number will be shown.
If it doesn't work the first time try again. It works on cell phones.

Comment: Ok, where do you want me to dial that? :)

Answer (score -1):

Click on mobile data,then click on sim applications,then click on “my services “then click on “my account”;then click on “show my number”....boom!……there you are.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Considering this question is 6.5 years old, you should probably edit your answer to include the iOS version you're referencing.