# Switching SIM cards or switching to a secret 2nd number

Tags: iphone, wifi

What would show up in my router logs if i was switching SIM cards or switching to a secret 2nd number . So far all I'm seeing is stuff like `initp01md@apple.com`, `init.ess.apple.com` `oscp.int3x.letsincrypt.org`, etc.

I'm just wanting to make sure I'm not bring obvious if someone  was switching. So please help me out if anyone knows.

Comment: Why would a SIM card access a router at all? It would be a 'telephone OTA' connection.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to ask... You tag iPhone, which makes sense with SIM, but then you talk about a router. Since you tag WiFi as well, maybe you wonder this: What happens with my WiFi when I change my SIM card in my iPhone? Will the router remember the phone and thus will WiFi still work? If that's your question, the answer is yes. WiFi is not affected by SIM card.

Answer (score 1):

> What would show up in my router logs if i was Switching sim cards or switching to a secret 2nd number .

**Nothing.**

One has nothing to do with the other.

- Your router, *routes* IP traffic from your network another network; in this case the Internet.
- Your [SIM card](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381981/119271) is what enables you to access the carrier's *cellular* network.  It's nothing more than an "access pass" to their network.  It doesn't even have anything to do with your phone number, secret or not, because it's tied to your *account*.